# Problem with setting a service in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs, aws-alb

I was trying to set up a ECS service running a container image on a cluster, but could not get the setup working.

I have basically followed the guide on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-blue-green.html, except that I was trying to host the containers on EC2 instances.

I wonder if the issue is related to the network mode (used "awsvpc").

## Expectation

It should show something on index.html on access witht eh ALB link

## Observation

When I tried to access with the load balancer link, it gives HTTP 503, and the health-check also showed unhealthy

[image: ALB_Link_HTTP_503]

And it seems ECS keeps "re-creating" the conatiners? (Forgive me as I am still not familiar with ECS)

[image: Containers_keep_re-creating]

Tried to access the container instance directly but also could not reach

[image: Container_instance_link]

[image: Conatiner_instance_could_not_reach]

I had a look on the ECS agent log (/var/logs/ecs-agent.log) on the container instance, the image should have been pulled sucessfully

[image: Image_pulled_successfully]

And the task should have been started

[image]

ECS service events

It seems it kept register and deregister target

[image: ECS_service_events]

Security groups have been set to accept HTTP traffic

## Setup

Tomcat server on container starts on port 80

- ALB

[image]

- Listener

[image]

- Target group

[image]

ECS task definition creation

```
{
"family": "TestTaskDefinition",
"networkMode": "awsvpc",
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "name": "TestContainer",
        "image": "<Image URI>",
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 80,
                "hostPort": 80,
                "protocol": "tcp"
            }
        ],
        "essential": true
    }
],
"requiresCompatibilities": [
    "EC2"
],
"cpu": "256",
"memory": "512",
"executionRoleArn": "<ECS execution role ARN>"
}
```

ECS service creation

```
{
"cluster": "TestCluster",
"serviceName": "TestService",
"taskDefinition": "TestTaskDefinition",
"loadBalancers": [
    {
        "targetGroupArn": "<target group ARN>",
        "containerName": "TestContainer",
        "containerPort": 80
    }
],
"launchType": "EC2",
"schedulingStrategy": "REPLICA",
"deploymentController": {
    "type": "CODE_DEPLOY"
},
"networkConfiguration": {
   "awsvpcConfiguration": {
      "assignPublicIp": "DISABLED",
      "securityGroups": [ "sg-0f9b629686ca3bd08" ],
      "subnets": [ "subnet-05f47b367df4f50d4", "subnet-0fd76fc8e47ea3be7" ]
   }
},
"desiredCount": 1
}
```

Comment: Since you've disabled public `assignPublicIp`, how do you ensure internet connectivity to download docker images?

Comment: I think "assignPublicIp" should be disabled for EC2 launchType. You will get the error "An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the CreateService operation: Assign public IP is not supported for this launch type." if specfiy enabled

Comment: Did you go to ECS Service tab in console, and look at events? It can have more info on what's happening.

Comment: Supplemented the events capture for the ECS service. Seems the target group is kept being registered and deregistered.

Comment: Are you sure that your tasks are running? If you remove the ALB out of the equation, are your containers serving the website correctly? This check would tell you if the issue is  limited to the ALB settings only or there is something with your containers themselfs.

Comment: Tried to create a service without using load balancer, made the following changes and it works. (1) Change nework mode from "awsvpc" to "bridge". Understand fargate launch type must use "awsvpc" network mode, but not sure if EC2 launch type must use "bridge" (2) Change the service health-check period to a larger value (e.g. 300s). It seems ECS treated the container instance unhealthy while the application has still not finished starting up, hence resulting in task kept being stopped and started.

Anyway, finally got it working with ALB, as well as in a CodePipeline flow, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'm glad it worked out:-) If you don't mind I could provide an answer for future reference?

Comment: @PatrickC. I would recommend using the health check grace period (https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/12/amazon-ecs-adds-elb-health-check-grace-period/), rather than just making the health check period longer. The grace period is specifically designed to allow slow starting applications more time before health checks kick in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

To investigate the issue, it was recommended to tested the ECS service without ALB. Based on the test, it was found that the ALB was treating the ECS service as unhealthy due to **long application starting time**.

The issue was solved by **increasing ALB health-check grace period** to (e.g. 300s).

> not sure if EC2 launch type must use "bridge"

You can use `awsvpc` on EC2 instances as well, but `bridge` is easier to use in this case.